# How can I get Django REST Authentication to work?

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble understanding how to get authentication to work.  I have set up a basic api, and I am trying to get any type of authentication to work (Basic Authentication to start with).  But no matter what I do, I am able to retrieve information from the database (using Postman) without entering a username or password.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my class:

```
class User(models.Model):
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('O', 'Other'), ('U', 'Unspecified'))
    )
    join_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25,)
```

Here is my view:

```
def user_tester(request):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        objs = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(objs, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Here are the relevant settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

Please advise on what I am doing wrong. I have some experience with Django, but none at all with authentication or permissions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using: `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)`, 
You should try the decorator before the definition of your "user_tester" method like:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def user_tester(request):
    objs = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(objs, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Good first answer. +1 from me

Comment: When I try adding the decorator, i get the following error: NameError: name 'permission_classes' is not defined

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I'll try my best :)

Comment: maybe you didn't import it from rest_framework.decorators.

Comment: Yes, that is what happened.  Your solution worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following line is dead code:

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

You are not creating a view by extending any of the django rest framework classes. it's only classes such as `APIView` that have a permissions_classes property that you can use to control authentiation. What you have is a simple function based view that merely returns a json. You are not even using django-rest-framework here. Your serialization code can be replaced by `to_dict` and `json.dumps`

If you want to continue with the current approach, decorate your FBV as

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
```

but with DRF you are better off with a CBV approach.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know much about Class Based Views.  I will look into how to use them.